# How to add a custom ID to a Wordpress page with pagination?

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a **Wordpress** page. When I add a custom ID to the URL, I get unwanted 'paged' page.

I want an overview of custom data from an API. When I click on a item, it should be redirected to '/mypage/10'. I already build a **plugin** with **shortcodes**, which retrieves the data from the API and displays it.

Then I want want to check if my page 'mypage' has a ID in the URL. If so, retrieves new data and shows it.

Looked across the internet, but can't find what I want.

Answer (score 0):

Validate the ID through GET parameters using

```
'mypage?ID=10'
```

And just check at the API side for:

```
$_GET['ID']
```

That should avoid any routing issues or having to rewrite the routes.
Also make sure you escape your variables properly.

**Update for SEO purpose**

As of taken directly from wordpress, you could add a custom route rule to your application, using the following:

```
function custom_rewrite_basic() {
  add_rewrite_rule('^mypage/([0-9]+)/?', 'index.php?page_id=$matches[1]', 'top');
}
add_action('init', 'custom_rewrite_basic');
```

Just edit the 'index.php?page_id=$matches[1]', to match your own destination.

Comment: This could be a solution indeed! But I want '/mypage/10', for better SEO and I think it looks better.

Comment: Updated my answer with an example to add additional routes in wordpress.

Comment: Thank you for your answers. But I need something else. I will try to explain my problem more detailed.

1. I made a page in Wordpress
2. Added a shortcode, for example: '[items_from_api]'
3. I'll fetch all data from the API and list everything
4. All items from API have a specific ID, for example: 8374
5. Clicking on a item will go to: '/mypage/8374'
6. In the shortcode, I'll have to check if the ID is present, to show specific content for only that item.
7. Now Wordpress has the idea I'm on page 8374 of the page '/mypage'.

I hope it is more clear now :).